# getting a default value to display in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

currently when the page loads the defualt value  of 10 displays which is what I want like so:
[image]

the custom amount shows:
[image]

but if I type something in the custom area and then delete it no default value is displayed. As shown here:

[image]

How can I get 10 to show up even if the user deletes their custom amount. I basically want 10 to always show if the user doesn't enter an amount or click a another button

here is my js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#donation-amount').keyup(function() {
      $('#display-amount').text($(this).val());
      });
     $( ".selectvalue" ).click(function() {
        $('#display-amount').text($(this).val());
     });

    $(".buttons .btn").click(function(){
        $(".buttons .btn").removeClass('active');
        $(this).toggleClass('active'); 
    });
    $('#display-amount').text($('#default').val());

});
```

and my html:

```
  <div class="choose-pricing">
          <div class="btn-group">
          <div class="buttons">
            <button type="button" id="default" class="btn btn-default selectvalue hover-color active" value="10">10</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default selectvalue hover-color" value="15">15</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default selectvalue hover-color" value="20">20</button>
            <input type="Custom" name="donation-amount" class="inpt-first form-control" id="donation-amount" onclick="if(this.defaultValue == this.value) this.value = ''" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value = this.defaultValue" value="Custom">
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="donation-amount-value" id="donation-amount-value">
          </div>
          <div class="money-donate">
            <div class="display-amount" id="display-amount">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: just check the custom textbox's value on each change, it its empty or equals zero then use the 10/15/20 whichever is pressed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this

store default in global and then apply when value is empty.

```
var defaultValue = 10;

$('#donation-amount').keyup(function() {
    if($(this).val()) {
         $('#display-amount').text($(this).val());
    } else {
        $('#display-amount').text(defaultValue );
    }
});
```

See in action here http://jsbin.com/guxukodace/edit?html,js,output

Comment: hmm now the 10 isn't showing up at all. I have this:

 var default = 10;
   $('#donation-amount').keyup(function() {
    if ($(this).val()) {
   $('#display-amount').text($(this).val());
    } else{
     $('#display-amount').text(default);
    }
  
   });

Comment: srry, `default` is keyword. Rename it to something else and it'll work

Comment: It's still not working. i changed the variable to defaultPrice and still nothing is showing

Comment: See the working example in attached Bin. Click the link and see you might be missing somrthing

Comment: nevermind! it works. I put it inside the document.ready and now I placed it outside! Thank you!